# Log4Net intemittently overwrites file instead of rolls file

Tags: log4j, log4net, logging

I have an intermittent problem with log4net.

I am working with a high-performance system with a lot of traffic to the log file. At peaks, 500-600 rows/sec are written to the log.

Since multiple processes are accessing the same log file, I use a RemotingAppender hosted by an ordinary Windows Service. The following is the config of my RemotingAppender host:

```
<appender name="FileLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file value="${REMOTELOG4NETLOGDIR}" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <encoding value="utf-8" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <maxsizerollbackups value="200"/>
    <maximumfilesize value="3MB"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss}&#9;%property{source}&#9;%    property{level}&#9;%message%newline"/>
    </layout>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
</appender>
```

Most of the time everything works fine. Files are rolled at date or when maximum file size is reached. But suddenly from time to time, when it should roll a file, it actually overwrites the file that should be rolled and erases all existing rows in that file, leaving a gap in the history of the log.

I am pleased for all possible answers which may help

Comment: I've got a similar issue with log4net.  Did you find a solution?